# Laravel unit test with upload file can not get file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on Laravel 5.6.

My code for unit test:

```
public function testUpload()
{
    Storage::fake('local');

    $this
        ->post(route('upload', ['file' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.txt', 1024)]))
        ->assertSuccessful();
}
```

But in controller `$request->file('file')` always `null`.

The `route('upload')` is correct but `dd($request->file('file'))` always `null` and `dd($request->file()` is empty array.

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the parameters in the 2nd argument of the `post` function. This is what you want:

```
public function testUpload()
{
    Storage::fake('local');

    $this
        ->post(route('upload'), ['file' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.txt', 1024)])
        ->assertSuccessful();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed my question. 
The `route` is not wrong, just wrong in my typo. I tested many times it goes to `/upload` but `dd($request->file('file')` always `null`. 
Route with name `upload` is using method `POST`.

Thank you!

Comment: @SangNguyen, Ok, I updated my answer. Kindly pass the arguments in the 2nd parameter of the `post` function

Comment: Wow, it's my mistake. Your answer is correct. Thanks!